# Issues with pagination with php

Tags: php, pagination

I have an `index.php` page from where I have included other pages with if statements as shown below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['dashboard'])) {
    include("dashboard.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['view_staffs'])) {
    include("view_staffs.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['delete_staff'])){
    include("delete_staff.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['edit_staff'])){
    include("edit_staff.php");
}
if(isset($_GET['group_companies'])){
    include("group_companies.php");
}
?>
```

I added paginations to the `view_staff` page with the url loking like `index.php?view_staff` so on adding the pagination code,

```
<?php 
if($page_no > 1){
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=1'>First Page</a></li>";
} ?>
    
<li <?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo "class='disabled'"; } ?>>
    <a <?php if($page_no > 1){
        echo "href='?page_no=$previous_page'";
    } ?>>Previous</a>
</li>
    
<li <?php if($page_no >= $total_no_of_pages){
    echo "class='disabled'";
} ?>>
    <a <?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages) {
        echo "href='?page_no=$next_page'";
    } ?>>Next</a>
</li>

<?php if($page_no < $total_no_of_pages){
    echo "<li><a href='?page_no=$total_no_of_pages'>Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a></li>";
} ?>
```

Whenever I click on next page, it shows a blank `index.php?page_no=2` with no content

Comment: Well, your index.php code doesn't appear to check for any `$_GET["page_no"]` variable. So please explain, based on your current code, what you expect to happen when your page receives that information?

Comment: Well of course you get no content shown, if you make the URL just `index.php?page_no=2` – that is missing the `view_staffs` parameter now, based on which you included `view_staffs.php` in the first place. _None_ of the parameters you look for in the first code block you have shown is set now, so your script includes _nothing_ at this point.

Comment: And please go read [ask]. A question title should summarize the main aspects of the _problem_, not contain parts of your life story, those are of little relevance.

Answer (score 1):

> whenever i click on next page, it shows a blank index.php?page_no=2
> with no content

yes, this is exactly what you have coded

```
echo "href='?page_no=$next_page'";
```

you have none of your paths like "dashboard" included in the URL - so how should the script know what to include?

All

```
if(isset($_GET['xxxxx'])) {
                include("xxxxxxx.php");
```

wil therefore fail.

Use chrome devtools to see the GET and POST variables or dump the $_GET array  if you are not sure what is available to your script.

As a start you will need to conserve the current path/url by using e.g. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and use it as additional argument for the pagination

```
 echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page_no={$next_page}'>NEXT PAGE</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to do two things to ensure your code works as you want it to. You need to obtain a reference the the current page ( `page_no` ) from your querystring to enable basic calculations to deduce `first`,`previous`,`next` and `last` pages and also to combine that with any pre-existing querystring values.

A simple PHP function that could be of use ( not tested extensively ) takes any existing variables from the GET array and combines them with a user-supplied array of parameter/value pairs. If there is a parameter supplied to the function that already exists in the querystring it will overwrite the previous version and use the newly supplied version. It returns a formatted string for use in the hyperlinks in the menu structure.

```
function createquerystring( $args=array() ){
    $req=array_merge( $_GET, $args );
    return http_build_query( $req );
}
```

One thing I would say - your code sets various querystring parameters such as `view_staffs` or `delete_staff` whereas I'd suggest setting a single parameter, such as `task` and then assigning `view_staffs` as the value etc. ie `?page_no=2&task=view_staffs` ~ it would make it easier to keep track of things and besides - the parameter really needs a value. A word of warning though - including files based upon querystring can be inherently dangerous so you should put in place a mechanism to check what is being passed in as a parameter to be included!

An example that grabs a `page_no` parameter if present and assigns to the `$page` variable which is then used to compare against 1 or `$total_no_of_pages`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body *{
                box-sizing:border-box;
                transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            }
            ul > li {
                display: inline-block;
                zoom:1;
                margin:0 0.5rem;
                border:1px dotted grey;
                padding:0.5rem;
                min-width:80px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            ul > li:hover{
                background:whitesmoke;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .disabled{
                background:rgba(100,0,0,0.1);cursor:not-allowed!important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php
            
                function createquerystring( $args=array() ){
                    $req=array_merge( $_GET, $args );
                    return http_build_query( $req );
                }
                
                
                $total_no_of_pages=10;
                
                # Obtain a reference to the page_no parameter from the querystring or set as 1 if it is not present
                $page=isset( $_GET['page_no'] ) ? $_GET['page_no'] : 1;
                
                # The menu will be within a simple UL element - a basic pattern using placeholders
                $pttn='<ul>%s %s %s %s</ul>';
                

                $first=$page==1 ? '<li class="disabled">First</li>' : sprintf( '<li><a href="?%s">First</a></li>', createquerystring( array( 'page_no' => 1 ) ) );
                
                $prev=$page > 1 ? sprintf( '<li><a href="?%s">Previous</a></li>', createquerystring( array( 'page_no' => $page - 1 ) ) ) : '<li class="disabled">Previous</li>';
                
                $next=$page < $total_no_of_pages ? sprintf( '<li><a href="?%s">Next</a></li>', createquerystring( array( 'page_no' => $page + 1 ) ) ) : '<li class="disabled">Next</li>';
                
                $last=$page >= $total_no_of_pages ? '<li class="disabled">Last</li>' : sprintf( '<li><a href="?%s">Last</a></li>', createquerystring( array( 'page_no' => $total_no_of_pages ) ) );
                
                # print the menu - substitute the placeholders for the named variables
                printf( $pttn, $first, $prev, $next, $last );

            ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Touching on the comment of including files and needing to ensure they are bonafide what you could do to aid the inclusion process would be to create an array containing the querystring parameter and the associated file and test if the parameter exists as a key...

```
<?php
    
    if( !empty( $_GET['task'] ) ){
    
        $task=filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'task', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        
        $allowed=array(
            'dashboard'         =>  'dashboard.php',
            'view_staffs'       =>  'view_staffs.php',
            'delete_staff'      =>  'delete_staff.php',
            'edit_staff'        =>  'edit_staff.php',
            'group_companies'   =>  'group_companies.php'
        );
        
        if( in_array( $task, array_keys( $allowed ) ) ){
            $file=$allowed[ $task ];
            require $file;
        }
    }
?>
```